# Appharbor won't build new web project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I just created a new application on AppHarbor and pushed a solution containing an ASP.NET MVC 3 web project. The odd case about this is it's a web project, not a web application, so it's a directory containing views, dll's, etc.. It's not a web application with a project file.

AppHarbor fails to build it:

> Build started 9/2/2012 7:54:11 PM. Project
>   "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln" on node 1 (default
>   targets). ValidateSolutionConfiguration:   Building solution
>   configuration "Release|Any CPU".
>   D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121:
>   The project configuration for project "HoustersForum" was not
>   specified in the solution file for the solution configuration
>   "Release|Any CPU". [D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln] Project
>   "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln" (1) is building
>   "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\HoustersForum.metaproj" (2) on node 1
>   (default targets). Build:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v
>   /HoustersForum -p ..\HoustersForum\ -u -f
>   D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\output_PublishedWebsites\HoustersForum\ 
>   ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory
>   'D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\HoustersForum\' doesn't exist.
>   [D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\HoustersForum.metaproj] Done Building
>   Project "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\HoustersForum.metaproj" (default
>   targets) -- FAILED. Done Building Project
>   "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln" (default targets) --
>   FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   (ValidateProjects target) ->
>   D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121:
>   The project configuration for project "HoustersForum" was not
>   specified in the solution file for the solution configuration
>   "Release|Any CPU". [D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln]
>
> "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\AppHarbor.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\HoustersForum.metaproj" (default target)
>   (2) -> (Build target) ->    ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory
>   'D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\HoustersForum\' doesn't exist.
>   [D:\temp\1yrhrtod.nii\input\HoustersForum.metaproj]
>
> ```
> 1 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.12

I've tried pulling down the code to another directory and it compiles fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 web application project and then copied all of the content into it from the web project folder. I then referenced the dll's in the web project's bin folder, and all was well.